# Re-installing Whatsapp

Tags: updates, whatsapp-messenger

I have been using Whatsapp on my Samsung Galaxy Ace 3 GT-S7275R for a long time.  Two days ago, a message popped up saying that my app was outdated.  So I started to update it.  It gets stuck on the updating, buffering all the time.  I have tried everything:  closing down my mobile phone and starting again, uninstalling Whatsapp and reinstalling - it still remains stuck on installing.  Can you advise please?
Anna Stivala

Answer (score 0):

A few questions to start. Does this happen with any other apps? Are you on Wifi or a Data connection?  Do you have the latest version of the play store?

You can try a few solutions.

1. Go to the app manager and clear the cache and data from "google play store" and "download manager".
2. uninstall updates from the google play store and download manager if they exist.
3. boot into recovery and clear the cache and dalvik.  To do this hold the volume up button when turning the phone on

Here is a little blurb explaining that it is safe to do and won't delete your data or apps
https://www.quora.com/I-want-to-wipe-dalvik-cache-on-my-phone-Will-this-delete-my-apps-or-data

4. Lastly you can try logging out of your Google account and back in

Give that a try and see if it helps
-Asloss

Answer (score -1):

Do you have enough storage space on your phone ? try deleting some useless app